# Using a function alias causes an "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'" error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.workflow_usage_bydep
    (@depId VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
    RETURN
        SELECT fn.slnxjob_id 
        FROM dbo.fn_dep_jobs(@depId, null, null, null, null, null, 0x08) fn
GO
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure workflow_usage_bydep, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

I cannot avoid GO and I know it belongs to SSMS and I have tons of megabytes code like that. Still don't know what to do. I can rename column inside function so in real code I do not need to use alias but looks odd.

If I remove the alias, then it works.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.workflow_usage_bydep
    (@depId VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
    RETURN
        SELECT slnxjob_id 
        FROM dbo.fn_dep_jobs(@depId, null, null, null, null, null, 0x08)
GO
```

> [i]Commands completed successfully.[/i]

Comment: If the code work without the alias, then just use the code without an alias.

Comment: Is the part you show us the full statement? Is there anything above? Did you simplify this? With a code *as provided* I'd assume this should work...

Comment: `GO` is not a SQL command. It is a batch delimiter understood by the client tools (e.g. batches run directly in SSMS  and not inside an `EXEC` string). Sounds like you are using it somewhere not understood. Without the alias `fn` it is just treating `GO` as an alias. Once you include the alias `fn` this interpretation is not valid (can't have an alias followed by an alias) hence the error.

Comment: @MartinSmith Great idea! Did not think of this... The OP might test this by using `SELECT GO.slnxjob_id...` to see, if the `GO` is taken as the alias...

Comment: Did you try to put the complete SELECT including the alias in parentheses? Otherwise the alias might be just considered not to be part of RETURN (so not the GO is the problem).

Answer (score -1):

If the parser "misunderstands" what you want to say, you can help it with parentheses:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.workflow_usage_bydep
    (@depId VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
    RETURN
        (SELECT fn.slnxjob_id 
        FROM dbo.fn_dep_jobs(@depId, null, null, null, null, null, 0x08) fn)
GO
```

Many times it is useful also for human interpretation so as it is optional use it if it helps.

Comment: I see the downvote but I can't improve the answer because it works. Unless you use a version with a related bug...